# Using a for loop to get multiple values that mean the same thing

Tags: javascript

How would I clean up this code?  Would I put it in a for loop and make it loop through and set the `rand2`, `rand3`, `rand4 = place`... there so there is a lot less lines of code (which is what I want)?  I need a cleaner way to do this, so it isn't so much space.

There needs to be different variables because I need the random to be different for each, so `rand2` = different random value than `rand3`.

```
var place = [74,111,148,185,222,259,296,333,370];
var random = [rand,rand2,rand3,rand4,rand5,rand6,rand7,rand8,rand9];
var rand = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand2 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand3 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand4 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand5 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand6 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand7 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand8 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var rand9 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];

var newrand = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var newrand1 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var newrand2 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var newrand3 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var newrand4 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var newrand5 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var newrand6 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var newrand7 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var newrand8 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var newrand9 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];

var old = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var old1 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var old2 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var old3 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var old4 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var old5 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var old6 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var old7 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var old8 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
var old9 = place[Math.floor(Math.random()*place.length)];
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ultimately? This doesn't make any sense as-is. Can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop. For example:

```
var place = [74, 111, 148, 185, 222, 259, 296, 333, 370];
var random = [];

for (var i = 0; i < place.length; ++i) {
    random.push(place[Math.floor(Math.random() * place.length)]);
}
```

This will fill `random` with random values as you did in your post with `rand2`, `rand3`, ...

And as [@raptor](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/26061/raptor) pointed out, instead of `random`, it would be better to use a different name to avoid confusion with possible existing JS function names. A better name should be related to the purpose or meaning of the variable, for example `randomPlaces` and `randomColors`.

Comment: 1 minor suggestion: I won't use variable names similar to any existing JS function names to avoid confusion.

Comment: Good point, added to my answer.